# Oracle Goldengate: Can I configure a specific column always to be captured in Extract even though not a Key Column

Tags: oracle, extract, oracle-golden-gate

I have a Goldengate configuration where **INSERTALLRECORDS** is used on the target database to replicate **INSERT**, **UPDATE** and **DELETE** operations on the source database to new records.

On the Target DB, the **Source DML Operation** and **Commit Time** are captured/recorded to the tables, via the use of **@GETENV('GGHEADER')** calls

This target DB is then read by an ETL process which applies records to Hadoop in the order they were committed to the target DB.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_test (id         NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
                      my_text    VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
                      date_added DATE          NOT NULL);
```

If I run the following SQL on the Source DB:

```
INSERT INTO my_test VALUES (1,'Inserting',SYSDATE);
UPDATE my_test SET my_text = 'Updating' WHERE id = 1;
DELETE FROM my_text WHERE id = 1;
```

this results in 0 records for ID=1 on the Source DB and 3 records on the Target DB, i.e.

```
ID    MY_TEXT     DATE_ADDED            GG_DML_TYPE     GG_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP
--    -------     ----------            -----------     -------------------
1     Inserting   12-12-2021 16:00:00   INSERT          12-12-2021 16:00:00
1     Updating    12-12-2021 16:00:00   SQL COMPUPDATE  12-12-2021 16:00:01
1                                       DELETE          12-12-2021 16:00:02
```

The corresponding tables in Hadoop are partitioned by **DAY_ADDED**, calulated from the Oracle DATE_ADDED column.

Currently, when applying a **DELETE** operation from Oracle, the ETL is having to scan all Hadoop partitions to find the matching **ID** record.

Consequently, to improve performance, I would like the **DATE_ADDED** column to always have its value captured in the Oracle GG Extract, so this will be present in the GG Trail file for all Source DML operations, including **DELETEs**

The only way I have found to do this is via the use of **LOGALLSUPCOLS** - however, this logs all columns in the Extract, which I don't want to do for some of our tables which have lots of columns and high volumes.

If anyone knows a way to always capture explicit columns, i.e. **DATE_ADDED** in this example, in the GG Extract, this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to take care of:

1. Make sure that the data for this column is added to supplemental log. You can make sure this happens - with running:

   ```
   add trandata my_test cols(date_added)
   ```

or by running SQL in the database:

```
   alter table my_test add supplemental log group grp1 (date_added) always;
```

2. You need to make sure that this column gets captured by extract process. To make sure this happens you should use in extract parameter:

   ```
   table my_test, cols(date_added);
   ```

This should be enough to include this columns in the trail. You can verify trail file if it actually contains *date_added* column;